# Javascript match-replace for link

Tags: javascript, jquery, preg-match, match

Theoretically,

I'v got link: "http://t.co/RANDOM_TEXT"

- RANDOM_TEXT = Changes in each post.

I want to change the **whole link** to "Read more..." **not** just the "http://t.co/".

Well, "http://t.co/blabla123" need to be "Read more..."

and "http://t.co/blabla6354" need to be "Read more..." Etc.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: You say ‘theoretically’… does that mean the links do not necessarily always start with `http://t.co/`?

Comment: You tagged this "preg-match" - are you saying you want to do this in PHP? Also, to clarify the requirement, are you saying you want to find URLs embedded in some other text and replace them with an `<a>` tag that links to that URL but displays the text "Read more..."? So `"Some text http://t.co/something more text"` would become `"Some text <a href="http://t.co/something>Read more...</a> more text"`? Please provide more context, perhaps a (short) sample of your HTML and JS.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
$('a[href^="http://t.co/"]').text('Read more...');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
  if($(this).html().match('t.co'))
    $(this).html('Read Mode');
});
```

Comment: This is potentially unsafe and not robust enough, need to incude the http in the match